# Почему показывает IllegalArgumentException: Not a primitive field?

Tags: java, android

Программа получает доступ к ресурсам в `raw` папке.

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(aRaw.getInt(null));
```

и в этой строчке в логе получаю такую ошибку, хотя программа работает нормально...

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a primitive field: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalChange com.story.krokosha.horrorstory.R$raw.$change
>   06-03 21:43:42.642 11176-11824/com.story.krokosha.horrorstory W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Native Method)
>   06-03 21:43:42.642 11176-11824/com.story.krokosha.horrorstory W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:460)
>   06-03 21:43:42.642 11176-11824/com.story.krokosha.horrorstory W/System.err:     at com.story.krokosha.horrorstory.activities.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:44)
>   06-03 21:43:42.642 11176-11824/com.story.krokosha.horrorstory W/System.err:     at com.story.krokosha.horrorstory.activities.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)

Что делаю не так?

Comment: видимо, поле, с которым работает `aRaw` имеет тип, отличный от `int`. Как вы его получаете?

Comment: @zRrr не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду... `aRaw` это `Field`... но ведь `getInt()` это метод класса  `Field`... Значит тут не должно быть ошибки...

Comment: вызовите `aRaw.getType()`, посмотрите, что там

Comment: там `int` ... вот лог getType() : int , и что это может означать?

Comment: ладно, вы, похоже, все правильно делаете (кроме использования reflection для работы с ресурсами, но тут вам виднее). Попробуйте Instant Run отключить, это сейчас кажется универсальное решение андроидопроблем

Comment: @zRrr Та не мне пока, что с Run удобно, если проблема только в этом, то я думаю ниче страшного если так будет работать... Так то вроде все правильно?

Answer (score 3):

`int` не может принимать значение `null`, ибо примитивный тип. Метод `aRaw.getInt(null)` пытается получить `int`. А передают ему `null`. Видимо в этом дело.

Comment: Я сделал так aRaw.getInt(0) и все равно ошибка таже

Comment: Попробуйте вывести `aRaw.toString();`.

Comment: Вывел получилось вот так лог :  `toString() : public static final int com.story.krokosha.horrorstory.R$raw.story_6` и что это может означать?